# Is there anyway to easily improt from Sugar CRM into Pentaho PDI Kettle?

Tags: integration, etl, sugarcrm, pentaho, kettle

It seems it used to be a plugin in 2009 but link does not work anymore (http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/SugarCRM+Plugin). Any suggestion/reference?

Thanks!

Comment: Why negative vote? Care to explain?

Comment: Don't know why your question is being voted down, but I checked around and haven't found any easy way to do this. Looks like the SugarCRM import plugin has been abandoned and hasn't been replaced.

Comment: Cannot see any reason for this to be downvoted either.

Comment: My limited experience with Sugar and Kettle led me to the conclusion that Kettle was more cumbersome than just necessary. Sugar has huge customization potential and a decent API. There's not much it can't do. I don't know what your end goal is with your Sugar data, but I'd suggest customizing Sugar to push data directly or using a better ETL (Talend?) for the job.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just access the database directly? that's what I've done in the past.
Alternatively try the API.

I suspect the only reason for the plugin in days gone past was simply that the webservice elements of PDI were not up to scratch at that time.

Comment: This post is really old right now, but I guess people (like me) keep looking for it. About accessing the database, it's an option IF you don't use an on demand instance (SugarCRM SaaS product). In this case, you rely on the Rest API (that is pretty complete right now).

Comment: good point. I'm not sure the SaaS existed when i wrote that answer :o

Answer (score 0):

Just made some tests as we are trying to extract data from SugarCRM On Demand instance and would like to use PDI as well.

Looks like it's pretty straightforward to get records fom SugarCRM REST API and convert it to whatever format you need using PDI. Below is a simple example and the output row generated.

[image: P]
*Write to log.0 - ------------> Linenr 1------------------------------
Write to log.0 - name = Filipe
Write to log.0 - date_entered = 2016-10-25T14:10:08+00:00
Write to log.0 - date_modified = 2016-10-25T17:49:01+00:00
Write to log.0 - idtype_c = PROFISSIONAL
Write to log.0 - rownum = 1*

In this example I was doing a GET from /accounts (REST Client step). You will need some date_entered / date_modified logic to know which records to retrieve, but I see no big deal to get it done.

We will build some PDI transformations to extract our Account/Opportunity/Phone/Address to a data mart, so if somebody have any further questions please feel free to ask as we will probably face new challenges.